# Filter results by relation items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a basic auth management.

Basically i have 3 tables:

```
users (App\User)
+ id
+ email
+ pass


groups (App\Group)
+ id
+ name

user_groups (App\UserGroup)
+ id
+ user_id
+ group_id
```

Obviusly the intermediate table is the "user_group" table. 
With this, i have a very easy post system associated with "groups" :

```
posts (App\Post)
+ id 
+ name
+ content

post_groups (App\PostGroup)
+ id
+ post_id
+ group_id
```

I want to allow the users to see only the posts without "group" or only when the user have the associated post group.

It is posssible with Laravel Eloquent or SQL? For example :

```
Posts::where(... logic here ...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: check documentation of `whereHas` in Laravel

Comment: what you have tried??

Answer (score 0):

If you have an eloquent relationship set up for Posts and Groups, you can get the Posts without a Group relationship like this:
`Posts::hasNot('group')->get();`

For getting Posts where the User has the Group, you can create an advanced where clause or do joins to filter out your query results.

Something like:

`Posts::has('group')->whereIn('group.user', Auth::user()->id);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries